# OpenGL glfwOpenWindow Doesn't work on Optimus video card

Tags: opengl, intel, optimus

I have a Geforce GT 540M, my laptop uses Optimus so it will 'switch' between the Intel GPU and the Geforce GPU depending on the applications/settings etc.

As far as I can tell on the line to open a window, it returns false:

```
if( !glfwOpenWindow( 1024, 768, 0,0,0,0, 32,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the     tutorials.\n" );
    system("pause");
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
```

The system command was just to confirm the error message I received.

Is there a way to force the compiler to recognize my graphics card? My assumption is that it can only spot my Intel gpu.

Comment: Still doesn't work, and this code worked on my desktop fine, the only difference I can think of was hardware, unless maybe I'm missing some GL files somewhere?

Comment: The compiler is not concerned with your particular OpenGL implementation or GPUs at all.

Comment: You haven't added if you are finding issues on Windows or Linux. If Linux, Optimus still have a lot of issues and I personally wouldn't even try to work with it under Linux.

Comment: Its Windows, and it works now as soon as the nvidia was set to be the active gpu when running VS 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for 32 depth bits. That's a rather unusual format. Typical choices are 24 depth bits and 8 stencil bits in a combined 32 bit depth-stencil format. Also you can use `glfwOpenWindowHint` to request an OpenGL-3 context, which should give you a context on the NVidia GPU.

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 0);

err = glfwOpenWindow(...);
/* ... */
```

Comment: Well, now I'm in a pickle because "now" everything seems to work, except that I did absolutely nothing other than to hibernate my laptop, move to a different room, turned it back on and tried again. And now it works, without any change to the code. Would anyone know why?

Comment: I think that what @datenwolf said should be taken in consideration. I know it might not be your case, but I have had intermittent problems when specifying textures with format GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT and internal format GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F (ATI cards).